# JSON transformation with JSONata

Tags: json, telegraf, jsonata

I am very new to JSONata, so I'm sorry if this is a very simple question or an impossible one.
I'd like to make the transformation from:

```
{
  "data":{
       "code1_value": 1,
       "code1_target": 2,
       "code2":3
   }
}
```

to

```
{
  "data":{
    "code1":{
          "value":1,
          "target":2
         }
     },
    "code2":3
}
```

The final goal is to include the transformation in the outputs plugin in Telegraf configuration file, for any key following that format code_tag. I tried several functions but none of them seems to work. Do you have any idea how to do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably easier ways to achieve that, but I was able to solve it using an ugly $reduce call:

```
{
  "data": $each(data, function($value, $key) {{
    "key": $key,
    "value": $value
  }}) ~> $reduce(function($acc, $entry) {(
    $contains($entry.key, "_")
      ? (
        $outerLevelKey := $split($entry.key, "_")[0];
        $innerLevelKey := $split($entry.key, "_")[1];
        
        $merge([$acc, { 
          $outerLevelKey: $merge([
            $lookup($acc, $outerLevelKey), 
            { $innerLevelKey: $entry.value }
          ])
        }])
      )
      : $merge([$acc, { $entry.key: $entry.value }])
  )}, {})
}
```

You can test it on the [Stedi Playground](https://www.stedi.com/jsonata/playground?statev2=eJyNUstugzAQ%2FJWVxcGWUBRIe6Fq%2BwHtHwCKLLNtUaiNjIkaAf322rjhlR56smd3Zna8kKakUa0WSEKCX7XGpimVtID3%2Bz6yZ5dJgIwU3PCMJDBCVxCqwOh45lWLrh6F64bh%2Bh2N68SrTuxKB1cZMjnc%2BgfIxQd1KIS3Vgpj09BgHBNCcMILg27KYOGosec0ZErkReOkgcH3EwQai1YgnW25ENYUpdHOlnqLQChpeCkb6js7526NjxlhngHwDPR6tQLVGtSveMbqBS%2BQPELQ1FVp%2FtCn%2B%2FxhISyl%2FK8wWgoXFp9o90xT%2F5Ru0dnmSibukmNZlVKntr4uY6VhIazJ3SZz8ru93bhr90lnbs5mNMxguiQ34ednb329nA2WNTD%2F36g%2B7g%2F9HclDck%2FyH2Fvz3g%3D)

Comment: Wow, that was fast, thank you! I could try to make easier, but I can start working from that.